# postfix sends mail from wrong domain / Python 3 code for sending utf8 mail

Tags: unicode, postfix, headers, mail-server, python3

I have a machine with two domain names, say a.com and b.com.

When I use postfix to send something from an address like foo@a.com, it replaces it with foo@b.com every time. My main.cf file specifies only a.com so I don't know where the b.com is coming from.

Here's the relevant part of **maillog**... the first line is the intiation of the message and then the 6th line is the one where jim@b.com mysteriously pops up.

```
mymachine sendmail[28543]: qA3NGbOR028543: from=jim@a.com, size=792, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<...@a.com>, relay=apache@localhost
mymachine postfix/smtpd[28546]: connect from b.com[127.0.0.1]
mymachine postfix/smtpd[28546]: 912F9758031: client=b.com[127.0.0.1]
mymachine postfix/cleanup[28549]: 912F9758031: message-id=<...@a.com>
mymachine sendmail[28543]: qA3NGbOR028543: to=someone@gmail.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30792, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as 912F9758031)
mymachine postfix/qmgr[28527]: 912F9758031: from=<jim@b.com>, size=1130, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant how I called this, but it's from some PHP mail() and I've ensured the -f flag is passed along. If any more info might help I'd be happy to deliver it!

Comment: I also found this which is a similar problem, but was not answered: http://serverfault.com/questions/144986/postfix-uses-hostname-instead-of-myhostname

Answer (score 0):

Following

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/mailman-developers/2001-March/008476.html

I found it was easier just to uninstall sendmail, install postfix, and use a Python script to send the mail. Here is the Python 3 code which I used to send the message (it needed to be internationalized hence the UTF-8 encodings).

```
import email.message, email.mime.text, smtplib, sys
from email.utils import parseaddr, formataddr
from email.header import Header
from email.charset import Charset

def format_address(name, email):
    if not name:
        return email
    name = Charset('iso-8859-1').header_encode(name)
    return formataddr((name, email))

def send_unicode_email(mFrom, mTo, mSubject, mBody):
    sender_name, sender_addr = parseaddr(mFrom)
    recipient_name, recipient_addr = parseaddr(mTo)

    composed = email.mime.text.MIMEText(mBody.encode('UTF-8'), _charset='UTF-8')
    composed['from'] = format_address(sender_name, sender_addr)
    composed['to'] = format_address(recipient_name, recipient_addr)
    composed['subject'] = Header(mSubject, 'UTF-8')

    srv = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    srv.send_message(composed)
    srv.quit()
```